# Differentiate between zoom feature and programmatic setExtremes call in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When you programmatically call `setExtremes` on a Highcharts axis, it fires the `setExtremes` and `afterSetExtremes` events for that axis.  Similarly, those two events are also fired when the user clicks and drags on the chart to zoom in.

Is there an easy way to differentiate between those two actions?  Specifically, I have a date range selector that, when changed, should call `setExtremes` on the chart. I also want the range selector to update when the chart is zoomed by dragging.  But if both actions fire the same events I have a loop.  I could put some logic in to prevent that, but it would be much more elegant if I could use differents events for the two separate actions or suppress the events when I'm programmatically calling `setExtremes`.

Comment: Could you recreate your example in jsfiddle.net? Because when you call setExtremes like http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes afterSetextremes doens't cause looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the source code, it looks like afterSetExtremes only fires when the extremes are actually changed, so that would indeed prevent looping.

Futhermore, there is a 5th parameter in the setExtremes function (undocumented in the API, but called eventArguments in the source code), which one can use to denote what process called the setExtremes function.